# Type inference failed for a Java class definition. How can I solve this?

Tags: java, kotlin, abstract-class, covariance

In Kotlin I have found that, in contrast to Java, the following can be done using [covariance](https://proandroiddev.com/understanding-generics-and-variance-in-kotlin-714c14564c47):

```
ArrayList<Dog> listOfDogs = listOf(dog1, dog2)
ArrayList<Animal> animalList = listOfDogs // No compiler error
```

In my situation I have an interface Message:

```
public interface Message {
     RawMessage toRawMessage();
}
```

For example I have an `Int32` Message:

```
public interface Int32 extends Message {
    // abstract methods
}
```

Now I have a method with a parameter `type` of type `Class<Message>`:

```
fun doSomethingWithType(type: Class<Message>) {
    // Implementation
}
```

The problem is that I am trying to pass a Java class extending from Message like:

```
doSomethingWithType(Int32::class.java)
```

But this gives me the following compiler error:

```
Expected type mismatch: 
required: Class<Message> 
found:    Class<Int32>
```

Why is this not working and how should I solve it?

Comment: `Class<Message>` is a class to the interface `Message`. What you need is: `Class<? extends Message>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is valid Kotlin code (assuming `Dog` is a subclass of `Animal`):

```
val listOfDogs: List<Dog> = listOf(dog1, dog2)
val listOfAnimals: List<Animal> = listOfDogs
```

The reason behind this is that `List` is an Kotlin interface defined as:

```
public interface List<out E> : Collection<E>
```

Unfortunately you can't do the same in pure Java, but you can do this:

```
List<Dog> listOfDogs = new ArrayList<>();
List<? extends Animal> listOfAnimals = listOfDogs;
```

Now, `doSomethingWithType` expects a `Class<Message>` while you're providing `Class<Int32>`, and `Class` is not covariant in `T`. In order to make that code compile you can do the following:

```
fun doSomethingWithType(type: Class<out Message>) { ... }
doSomethingWithType(Int32::class.java)
```

This will work as long as you'll only pull out `T` from `Class<T>`, i.e. `Class` will only produce type `T`.